# Javascript: Get XHR response from click() without firing the click method

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I have a web crawling tool which crawls certain sites, compiles a list of links on the front page.

One particular website which I want to crawl is problematic. The "links" are not `<a>` elements, rather `<div>` elements, and have no "onclick" attribute either, so `.getAttribute` is not an option.

Upon clicking on the link, an XHR request is sent, the URL is returned and the new page is loaded.

What I require is the URL, without the new page ever loading.

Is this possible (preferably with JS)?

Comment: Unless the URL is present in the element's markup (say, in a `data-` attribute), you appear to be short of luck.

Comment: So how is their website detecting a click event if there isn't a click event handler, or a hyperlink with an href attribute? 
Are they attaching click handlers after the page loads, and perhaps your crawler isn't seeing that?  (what's the URL?)